# Android layout design for many menu options

Tags: android

What is the best way to go about designing an Android application that features quite a bit of formulas and conversions?  I was thinking that multiple Activities with ListViews sort of like a tree with the leaves being the actual calculations.  However, after reading Android design principles it's better to avoid a pure navigational structure and try to reduce the deepness of the app.

For example:

```
Main Menu
  Conversions
    Weight
    Distance
  Distance - Speed - Time
    Calculate air speed
    Calculate distance traveled
  Weather
    METAR
    TAF
```

So by the 3rd or 4th screen we've reached the actual individual calculator.  Does this make sense?  And if it does, is there a better way of designing this (maybe using action bars or tabs)?

Comment: Why not use a expandable listview, with each section separated out and use that as the "main" screen instead? Interesting question BTW :)

Comment: What do you mean by this?  It sounds like this is what I'm referring to.

Comment: a row item that has a section called Conversions, tap that, it expands into two row items, "Weight", "Distance", likewise for "Distance - Speed - Time", tap that, expands into two row items "Calculate air speed", "Calculate distance traveled"

Comment: Sometimes the simplest of UI, the old and reliables can actually work out beneficial, as in the case of using a expandable listview with child rows, that eliminates the nesting ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a very simple UI concept of Expandable Listviews, in which there is more than one child row for each section of the parent row, by tapping on the "Conversions", could expand into sub-rows, likewise for each section as you see fit, and treat that as a *Main Menu* in a sense of a word, that is, your main application screen.

The nice advantage is that the nesting of the menus in the Android way, is eliminated and can accomodate as many as you wish.

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense now.  So then from the Main Menu screen, it's possible to have all the possible formulas listed (by expanding every row).  Then by clicking a leaf it will start a new Activity.

Comment: Correct :) Yes, that is it :)

Answer (score 1):

The third or forth screen sounds like it's too deep down the rabbit hole, how about instead having multiple tabs for each "type"?

For example;

```
[Conversions][Distances][Weather]
```

If you add an `ActionBar` to it, you could have a type of filter as the GMAIL app has (where you select the account) and use it to toggle the different "modes" so to speak.

Another approach would be to have it all in one screen, just that you switch the active layout (or perhaps `Fragment`) via the filter I mentioned above.

Check out the GMAIL app, and you'll see what I mean in terms of the filter. :-)

Comment: like the reference to the matrix... the red pill dammit, not the blue pill aiiieee..... "it's too deep down the rabbit hole" ... :) That made me smile!

Comment: Every post should have a bit of Matrix in 'em, that's what keeps them alive! :D

Comment: LOL! +1 ;) Very good Morpheous, have you found the *Matrix*? :D